# Why is my output list short of several items?

Tags: python

I tried making a makeshift encrypter, but nothing seems to be wrong and my output is several characters short. Help!

This is my code:

```
#Encrypter v1

import random, os, sys

inputstring = input("What is your sentence?(Remove all punctuation!)\n")

inputstringnum = input("How many levels of encryptiion? Maximum encrytion lentgh is 24.\n")

inputstringnum1 = int(inputstringnum)

#Code

def list_randomizer(inputstring1):
    inputlist = list(inputstring1)
    outputlist = inputlist[::-1]
    return outputlist

def list_changer(var1, crypt_num):
    alphabet_list = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") #To find the index
    caps_list = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    output_list = []
    for item in var1:
        tmp2 = var1.pop(0)
        if tmp2 in alphabet_list == True:
            tmp3 = alphabet_list.index(tmp2)
            tpm3 = int(tmp3) #Failsafe
            object_int = tmp3 + crypt_num #Encrpyting on desired depth
            tmp4 = alphabet_list[object_int]
            output_list.append(tmp4)
        if tmp2 in caps_list == True and tmp2 in caps_list != True:
            tmp3 = caps_list.index(tpm2)
            tmp3 = int(imp3)
            object_int = tmp3 + crypt_num
            tmp4 = caps_list[object_int]
            output_list.append(tmp4)
        else:
            output_list.append(tmp2)
    return output_list

temp1 = list_changer(list_randomizer(inputstring), inputstringnum1)

print(temp1)
```

Comment: Please show the input, actual output and expected output.

Comment: How could this ever be True `if tmp2 in caps_list == True and tmp2 in caps_list != True:`? It is also  `tmp2` not `tpm2` and `imp3 `is not defined anywhere

Comment: You can use `ord` to simplify your checks about which type of character tmp2 is: `if 96 < ord(tmp2) < 123: print("tmp2 is in alphabet_list")` and `if 64 < ord(tmp2) < 91: print("tmp2 is in caps_list")` and use the value of `ord(tmp2)` to compute your `object_int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other stated, iterating over `var1` **and** popping items from it leads to your first issue of having less character in your output than in your input.

You also have overly complicated code including:

- usage of `list('abc')` instead of directly using strings to iterate
  over or search indexes.
- comparisons against `True` which are not necessary in python: `if a:` or `if t in ['a','b']:` are perfectly valid tests in python.
- usage of handcrafted lists of characters. Either use the [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#ord) builtin function or the `ascii_lowercase` and `ascii_uppercase` strings from the [`string` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html).

I’d simplify your code to:

```
def list_changer(input_string, encrypt_level):
    output_list = []
    for character in input_string:
        char = ord(character) # convert character to ascii code
        if not ((96 < char < 123) or (64 < char < 91)):
            # if not ascii alphabetic value, ignore it
            output_list.append(character)
            continue
        offset = 97 if char > 96 else 65 # check whether it is upper or lower case
        char = (char - offset + encrypt_level) % 26 # encode it
        character = chr(char + offset) # convert back to a character
        output_list.append(character)
    return ''.join(output_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inputstring = input("What is your sentence?\n")
    encrypt = int(input("How many levels of encryption?\n"))
    computed_string = list_changer(inputstring[::-1], encrypt)
    print(computed_string)
```

Comment: There's a bug in how you handle non-ascii characters - you may want to add a `continue` iat the end of the `if not ((96 < char < 123) or (64 < char < 91)):` branch.

Comment: Thanks very much, I didn't know anything about the ascii alphabetical value or I would have used it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with these 2 lines inside your `list_changer` function-

```
for item in var1:
    tmp2 = var1.pop(0)
```

You are popping out of the same list that you are iterating on.

```
tmp2 = item
```

instead of

```
tmp2 = var1.pop(0)
```

This is why you get wrong number of results.
So basically, your `list_changed` function should look like -

```
def list_changer(var1, crypt_num):
    alphabet_list = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") #To find the index
    caps_list = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    output_list = []
    for item in var1:
        tmp2 = item
        if tmp2 in alphabet_list:
            tmp3 = alphabet_list.index(tmp2)
            tpm3 = int(tmp3) #Failsafe
            object_int = tmp3 + crypt_num #Encrpyting on desired depth
            tmp4 = alphabet_list[object_int]
            output_list.append(tmp4)
        elif tmp2 in caps_list:
            tmp3 = caps_list.index(tpm2)
            tmp3 = int(imp3)
            object_int = tmp3 + crypt_num
            tmp4 = caps_list[object_int]
            output_list.append(tmp4)
        else:
            output_list.append(tmp2)    
    return output_list
```

**Other problems**
 - Problem 1

```
tmp2 in alphabet_list == True
```

Will always yield `false` since your `alphabet_list` is a list and this evaluates to -

```
tmp2 in (alphabet_list == True)
```

Replace this with -

```
if tmp2 in alphabet_list:
```

- Problem 2

```
if tmp2 in caps_list == True and tmp2 in caps_list != True:
```

Will never hold true.
REplace with this -

```
elif tmp2 in caps_list
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all , `==` and `in` do not behave well because of operator chaning.

```
a in ['a','b'] == True
```

The above returns False as it becomes - `(a in ['a','b']) and (['a','b'] == True)` .

You do not need to check against `True` , just directly use its result in the condition.

Secondly, when you do -

```
for item in var1:
```

You are iterating over the elements of `var1` , then if you do `var1.pop(0)` , it will miss the next element.

Thirdly, your second `if` should be a `elif` , otherwise it is causing same element to get encrypted and put in list as well as causing the unencrypted to be added to list as well.

Code-

```
import random, os, sys

inputstring = input("What is your sentence?(Remove all punctuation!)\n")

inputstringnum = input("How many levels of encryptiion? Maximum encrytion lentgh is 24.\n")

inputstringnum1 = int(inputstringnum)

#Code

def list_randomizer(inputstring1):
    inputlist = list(inputstring1)
    outputlist = inputlist[::-1]
    return outputlist

def list_changer(var1, crypt_num):
    alphabet_list = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") #To find the 

index
    caps_list = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    output_list = []
    for item in var1:
        tmp2 = item
        if tmp2 in alphabet_list:
            tmp3 = alphabet_list.index(tmp2)
            tpm3 = int(tmp3) #Failsafe
            object_int = tmp3 + crypt_num #Encrpyting on desired depth
            tmp4 = alphabet_list[object_int]
            output_list.append(tmp4)
        elif tmp2 in caps_list:
            tmp3 = caps_list.index(tmp2)
            tmp3 = int(tmp3)
            object_int = tmp3 + crypt_num
            tmp4 = caps_list[object_int]
            output_list.append(tmp4)
        else:
            output_list.append(tmp2)
    return output_list

temp1 = list_changer(list_randomizer(inputstring), inputstringnum1)

print(temp1)
```

Comment: actually `in` and `==` doesn't behave well because of precedence but because of operators chaining. `a in ['a','b'] == True` translates to `(a in ['a','b']) and (['a','b'] == True)`

Comment: There are numerous errors in this code, what is `elif tmp2 in caps_list and tmp2 in caps_list:` why would you check the same condition twice? Where is `imp3` coming from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I already had removed the double checking, fixed the typos as well.

Comment: Also there is no need to keep using lists. `in` works with strings too.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger True, I just pointed out the basic issues in the code, fixing which should allow the user to get the result he expects. I am guessing improvements on the code can be done by the user itself, afterwards.

Comment: There is also no need to call list on a string, a string can be iterated and indexed exactly as a list can,  it would also make a lot more sense to use a dict to do lookups